# How do I enumerate all the TDI drivers installed on a Windows system?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I suspect that a TDI filter driver is causing network issues on a Windows 2008 R2 system.

How do I enumerate all TDI filter drivers installed, so that I can look for the suspect TDI filter driver and remove it?

Thanks.